# Twitter Bootstrap collapse opened for smartphones

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have such code snippet:

```
 <div class="alert alert-info">Today's news
        <div class="pull-right"><a class="btn btn-small" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#newsDiv"><i class="icon-chevron-down"></i></a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="newsDiv" class="collapse in">
        Today something happened<br>
        Also yesterday happened<br>
        Maybe tomorrow<br>
    </div>
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gfUXW/

I want this behaviour: When user visits with phone (width 480 px and below) collapse will be closed, when user visits with a bigger device collapse will be opened autmatically.

To make it responsive I need to do by CSS rules. But I couldn't figure how can I join [responsive classes](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive) of bootstrap like "visible-phone" and "collapse in" class.

Comment: I think that you have to read the dedicated page in [BOOTSTRAP](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#navbar)

Comment: I have a navbar in top so I don't prefer two navbars. But also collapsible navbar dictates 979 px for switching. I must change less to switch for smartphones width.

Comment: Can I have some feedback on my answer?  Is this question resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the collapse is a javascript plugin, I think the answer lies in using some javascript.

If you remove the `in` class, it will leave your collapse closed by default, which is useful to know.  Then you can check this when the document is ready.

```
  if ($(window).width() > 480) {
    $(".collapse").collapse('show');   
  }
```

The methods are in the documentation:  [Bootstrap Collapse](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse)

See it in action by clicking run with different screen widths:  http://jsfiddle.net/LaAWc/1/

If you want this checked constantly, you'll have to poll with a timer to keep checking. If that interests you, see [How to detect in jquery if screen resolution changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575772/how-to-detect-in-jquery-if-screen-resolution-changes)

Comment: I would prefer solving this without javascript, but it seems there is no other way..

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the responsive css file first
then you can add the logic to the relevant media queries
http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive

small example based on yours:

- when you open following link with a device larger 480px, you will see everything
- when you open with a device smaller 480px; you will see nothing (change browser size)

http://jsfiddle.net/iambnz/gfUXW/2/

```
@media (max-width:480px) { 
         .in{ display:none; }
         .alert-info{ display:none; }
         }
```