# Add/Remove multiple classes on multiple elements simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, element, class-names

What I'm trying to achieve is using a single element, by onclick, is add and remove 2 class names on 2 independent elements simultaneously.

Here is my element I'm using to trigger the js/jquery.

```
<div class="top-tool-buttons"><a href="" id="myElementId"></a></div>
```

Then once clicked turn these elements from this (menu_hide & lockscreen_on):

```
<div id="somename1" class="list-nav menu_hide"></div>

<div id="somename2" class="screen lockscreen_off"></div>
```

to this (menu_show & lockscreen_off):

```
<div id="somename3" class="list-nav menu_show"></div>

<div id="somename4" class="screen lockscreen_on"></div>
```

Jquery/JS

```
document.getElementById('#myElementId').addEventListener('click', function() {
.removeClass('menu_hide lockscreen_on').addClass('menu_show lockscreen_off');
}, false);

document.getElementById('#myElementId').addEventListener('click', function() {
.removeClass('menu_show lockscreen_off').addClass('menu_hide lockscreen_on');
}, false);
```

Open to better practices too as I'm trying to achieve unnoticeable page loading.

Comment: Side note, IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: If you are going to use jQuery at all, use it for selectors as well. Your code will shrink by 50%+. e.g. `$('#myElementId').click(function()`

Comment: Thanks. Just as fyi... I'm totally a JS/Jquery novice. In other practice suchas CSS etc... I get using unique ID, but since I was trying to trigger the same thing, I didn't know if the ID had to be attached to all items being triggered. For sake of better question and practice I'll revise that.

Comment: You can attach triggers via classes or id's or attributes, but id-based selectors are the fastest as the browser maintains a lookup-table of all the unique ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are worrying too much about changing multiple attributes causing screen flickers etc. All these operations will complete in sequence before the page renders :)

You can simplify your code using jQuery though:

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/7b75Q/

```
$('#myElementId').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
   // Toggle all 4 classes off or on
   $('#somename1').toggleClass('menu_hide menu_show');
   $('#somename2').toggleClass('lockscreen_on lockscreen_off');
});
```

As noted you must have unique ids for elements. Thanks for updating your example. Have adjusted answer to suit.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Exactly what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: This may be not possible and way out there... but is there a way to detect if a device or url is mobile based allow the somename2 toggle class to be used. But otherwise don't allow??? But always allow somename1 to be used. That may be a whole other ball of wax.

Comment: You can detect by either resolution, or browser sniffing. The question becomes what do "you" consider to be mobile-based? :)

Comment: It's a responsive web design... however I'd only allow mobile CSS to be used when browser detects .mobi, or... maybe better by using @media to detect lower than 500px width allow #somename2 to be in use. Currently it's using at media of below 500px do X.

Comment: If you use `bootstrap` there is a nice trick to add resolution change events. Let me know if you are.

Comment: I'm not but... I know of resolution change events using jquery. I've never done it before though.

Comment: `(function () {
    var width = screen.width,
        height = screen.height;
    setInterval(function () {
        if (screen.width !== width || screen.height !== height) {
            width = screen.width;
            height = screen.height;
            $(window).trigger('resolutionchange');
        }
    }, 50);
}());`

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575772/how-to-detect-in-jquery-if-screen-resolution-changes]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create new elements to do this.

```
$('#myElementId').on('click',function() {
    if($("showname1").hasClass("menu_hide")){
        $("#showname1").removeClass("menu_hide").addClass("menu_show");
        $("#showname2").removeClass("lockscreen_off").addClass("lockscreen_on");
    } else {
        $("#showname1").removeClass("menu_show").addClass("menu_hide");
        $("#showname2").removeClass("lockscreen_on").addClass("lockscreen_off");
    }
});
```